# Rational points on a weighted projective surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

The equation

$$\displaystyle y^2 = f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$$

with $f$ a non-singular quartic form in three variables defines a del Pezzo surface of degree 2. I am interested in the similar construction

$$\displaystyle y^2 = f_1(x_1, x_2, x_3) f_2(x_1, x_2, x_3)$$

where $f_1, f_2$ are quadratic forms defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there anything known about the study of rational points for such surfaces in the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,2)$?

Comment: The fibre product of the quadric surfaces $y_i^2=f_i(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ over $\mathbb{P}^2$ (given by co-ordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$) maps to your surface. So perhaps that says something?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127654/parametrization-of-solutions-of-diophantine-equation